# Discord.py welcomer doesn't work and I don't receive any errors. How to solve it?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I can't understand why my code doesn't work... I mean, when a member join the server, the BOT doesn't do anything, and I don't receive any error from the terminal. Please help me I'm desperate.

```
import asyncio
import discord
from discord import client, message
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"{client.user} is now online! ID: {client.user.id}")
    activity = discord.Game(name="!help")
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.idle, activity=activity)


@client.event
async def on_member_join(ctx, member):
    await ctx.send(f'Welcome {member.mention}')

#I made it as simple as possible, but it still doesn't work.

client.run(token="tokentokentokentokentokentoken")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`on_member_join` only takes 1 argument.

Also, you need to enable the `Members Intent` for this to work.

```py
import discord

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)
```

Then enable it on your bot's dashboard. More info on how to do that in the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html).

Comment: Ok, something's happened, but I receive an error now, called "RuntimeError: event loop is closed"

Comment: I'm guessing that is because you did ``run(token=[token_goes_here])``, passing the token as a `kwarg` instead of a normal argument. Either that or you're not running it properly.

Comment: Ok, I found the problem, I didn't activate the `Server Member Intents` on the discord developer portal. Thanks a lot bro.

Comment: If it helped you should mark this answer as correct

Answer (score 0):

`discord.on_member_join(member)` [Documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_member_join#discord.on_member_join) only accept one parameter member.

do implement following code

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join( member):
    await member.send(f'Welcome {member.mention}')
```